# The settimeout is returning all values of the object, why is it not returning only one value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, use-effect, object-literal

```
const RequestStatus = () => {
    const status = 'SUCCESS'
    
    const object = {
        SUCCESS: console.log('Success'),
        PROGRESS: console.log('Progress'),
        ERROR: console.log('Errror'),
    }
   
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            return object[status]
        }, 5000)
    }, [status])
}
```

Comment: Return values from `setTimeout` are ignored. What are you trying to do? If you have a `useEffect`, you probably want to have a `setState` in it somewhere.

Comment: You'll want `SUCCESS: () => console.log('Success'),` then later do `object[status]()` instead

Answer (score 1):

You see all three statuses logged because you are calling all console.log when you create your object

Here are two ways you can modify your code to fix this

In the first method (which is the one I recommend) I am mapping the messages to the status codes and getting the approprite message using object[status]

```js
const RequestStatus = () => {
    const status = 'SUCCESS'
    
    const object = {
        SUCCESS: 'Success',
        PROGRESS: 'Progress',
        ERROR: 'Errror',
    }
   
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(object[status]);
        }, 5000)
    }, [status])
}
```

In the second one I create lambda functions for each status code that define what happens when that status code occurs

```js
const RequestStatus = () => {
    const status = 'SUCCESS'
    
    const object = {
        SUCCESS: ()=>{console.log('Success')},
        PROGRESS: ()=>{console.log('Progress')},
        ERROR: ()=>{console.log('Errror')},
    }
   
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            object[status]();
        }, 5000)
    }, [status])
}
```